# How declare function to pass one argument argv[i] at a time? In C

Tags: c, pointers, argv

While debugging when I jump to function parseLayerFile filename is (char **) 0x40a04e <_Jv_RegisterClasses+4235342>... How to correct the declaration to get valid filename value?

```
void parseArgs(WRAPPER_t *w, int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int i;
   for (i=1 ;i<argc ;i++) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i],"-layers") == 0) {
          i++;
          parseLayerFile(argv[i]);
        }
    } // for
}

int parseLayerFile(WRAPPER_t * w, char*filename[]){
  unsigned char * buffer; size_t size;
  size = get_fileContent(filename, &buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
      WRAPPER_t * w;
      w = create_wrapper(); // w - main object
      threads_init(w);
      parseArgs(w, argc, argv);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: having `char*filename[]` as a function parameter means `filename` is a pointer to pointers to char; it is not a string.

Comment: I tried this: `int parseLayerFile(WRAPPER_t * w, char*filename)` but filename has wrong value. Whilst in parseArgs argv[i] is 0x3e27bc "layers.cfg", the filename variable in parseLayerFile is wrong: 0x40a04e <_Jv_RegisterClasses+4235342> "-layers"

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and mind them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int parseLayerFile(WRAPPER_t * w, char*filename[])
```

expects two parameters.

You are calling it with only one parameter:

```
parseLayerFile(argv[i]);
```

As none of the argument suit your needs, fix the function as follows:

```
int parseLayerFile(const char * filename)
{
  unsigned char * buffer; 
  size_t size = get_fileContent(filename, &buffer);
}
```

Comment: Wow. I wonder why compiler did not print error for this. It looks like undefined behavior. It did not report the error even when I have used forward declaration in header file. Thanks. Solved